# Invite keys for signup (no device)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a system which, upon signup, Rails checks to see if a user has an invite code. My original idea was to make a table separate from "users" with a list of permitted registration tokens and have my system save the user if the invitation token is valid, with a column in the User table holding the invite key the person used to sign up. How can I implement this?

Comment: How much detail were you hoping for? Do you already have a registration process and/or authentication system in place?

Comment: Not a ton of detail is needed- I just need to be able to restrict signups to those who have invite codes.

Comment: Hey @vkjbrjb, did my answer end up working out for you?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's say you have a `User` model and an `Invite` model. I would probably set the relationship up like this.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invite

  # ...
end

# app/models/invite.rb
class Invite < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users

  # ...
end
```

Next, I would create a form object to handle the combination of user sign up logic and invite code logic:

```
# app/models/user/registration_form.rb
class User::RegistraionForm 
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :invite_code

  validate :check_user
  validate :check_invite_code

  def submit
    if valid?
      user.invite = invite
      return user.save
    end

    return false
  end

  private
    def check_user
      unless user.valid?
        user.errors.each do |attribute, message|
          errors.add(attribute, message)
        end
      end
    end

    def user
      @user ||= User.new(name: name, email: email, password: password,
        password_confirmation: password_confirmation)
    end

    def check_invite_code
      unless invite.present?
        errors.add(:base, 'You must have a valid invite code')
      end
    end

    def invite
      @invite ||= Invite.find_by(code: invite_code)
    end
end
```

This assumes that the `Invite` model has an unique attribute called `code` for each record.

Finally, you can create a registration controller to user the newly created form object:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @registration_form = User::RegistraionForm.new
  end

  def create
    @registration_form = User::RegistraionForm.new(registration_params)

    if @registration_form.submit
      # success! redirect or do something here
    else
      flash[:alert] = @registration_form.errors.full_message.to_sentence
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def registration_params
      params.require(:registration_form).permit(:name, :email, :password,
        :password_confirmation, :invite_code)
    end
end
```